# How to install Hive Metastore in Kubernetes?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, hive-metastore

I am working on a project on Kubernetes where I use Spark SQL to create tables and I would like to add partitions and schemas to an Hive Metastore. However, I did not found any proper documentation to install Hive Metastore on Kubernetes. Is it something possible knowing that I have already a PostGreSQL database installed ? If yes, could you please help me with any official documentation ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hive on MR3 allows the user to run Metastore in a Pod on Kubernetes. The instruction may look complicated, but once the Pod is properly configured, it's easy to start Metastore on Kubernetes. You can also find the pre-built Docker image at Docker Hub. Helm chart is also provided.

https://mr3docs.datamonad.com/docs/k8s/guide/run-metastore/

https://mr3docs.datamonad.com/docs/k8s/helm/run-metastore/

The documentation assumes MySQL, but we have tested it with PostgreSQL as well.